# What regex will capture multiple instances inside braces/parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

How do I use regex to capture, say, every run of space characters `\ +` inside brackets? For example, in the string,
`"abc   and 123 {foo-bar     bar baz } bit {yummi tummie} byte."`
I should find four matches inside `{}` -- but nothing else. Assume Python language and that the string content is unknown.

**EDIT:** Also assume that there are NO nested braces.

Comment: Are there nested braces?

Comment: May there be cases like these: `abc { abc } a { a }` or `abc { a { b } }`?

Comment: @gill Nope. No nested braces.

Comment: @Norman: Multiple braces -- yes.

Comment: In Your edited example, matching four spaces - in first bracket - any possibility that order is reversed ? ("yummi tummie" before "foo-bar    bar baz ") ?

Comment: Maybe instead of "every space character", you mean "every **run** of space characters"? There are 7 such spaces in your example, but 4 consecutive runs.

Comment: @gill: Ok, you're right. I changed the wording to reflect this.

Comment: Can you give an upper bound for the number of "runs of spaces" inside *one* pair of brackets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[A lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can check if there is a `}` ahead without any `{` in between.

```
\s+(?=[^{]*})
```

- `\s` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for whitespace character `[ \t\r\n\f]`. Match [`+`](https://www.google.at/#q=regex+quantifier) one or more.
- `(?=[^{]*})` looks ahead if there is a `}` with any [non `{`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) in between.

[Demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mJ0sZ4/1)

Comment: Good one, assuming there is no dangling `}`

Comment: Just a [quick demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6n8oyU) to round up your beautiful regex.

Comment: This matches spaces outside of `{}` pairs.

Comment: @bobble Ah, sorry, I just said the same thing as gill about "dangling `}`".

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = 'abc   and 123 {foo-bar     bar baz } bit {yummi tummie} byte.'
>>> inside_braces = re.findall(r'\{.*?\}', s)
>>> spaces_inside_braces = [re.findall(r' +', match) for match in inside_braces]
>>> [match for mlist in spaces_inside_braces for match in mlist]  # flatten list
['     ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

1. We need `?` in the `r'\{.*?\}'` to match braces non-greedily.
2. It's possible to do all of it in one line but that would be too long.
3. I can't think of a way to do all of it with just one regex. It seems not possible because we have recursion (even left-recursion): i.e., a pattern should be matched *after* `{` and *any number* of `.w`s. IIRC regex can't deal with this, even if look-behind didn't require a fixed-length pattern.

Comment: I like this idea, but OP said inside braces but after and before any words inside braces.

Comment: @JustMe You're right. Don't know how I missed read that. Will fix.

Comment: @JustMe Oh no... OP didn't say "after and before any words". But I misread the question in another way... Fixed it.

Comment: well, You are right ;) but it seems OP is not quite specific - says "every space" in bracket but then only four spaces - while between words there are five spaces, and two more after words, total - 7.

Comment: @JustMe I think OP meant "every **run** of space characters", since the expected number of matches is 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use an [alternate regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), then you *can* do it with a single regex. It is complex and unreadable, though. But it handles dangling braces correctly.

**The `regex` module supports accessing all of a capture group's previous matches**, which is essential for the following to work:

```
>>> import regex
>>> # The regex behavior version seems to make no difference in this case, so both '(?V0)...' and '(?V1)...' will work.
>>> pattern = r'(?V0)[{]   (?P<u>\s+)?  (?: (?: [^\s}]+ (?P<u>\s+) )*  [^\s}]+ (?P<u>\s+)? )?   [}]'
>>> string = 'abc   and 123 {foo-bar     bar baz } bit {yummi tummie} byte.'
>>> [s for m in regex.finditer(pattern, string, regex.VERBOSE) for s in m.captures('u')]
['     ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
```

Simply put, this regex finds matches of the form `'{' blanks? ((nonblanks blanks)* nonblanks blanks?)? '}'` and assigns all blank parts to the same capture group named `u` (`(?P<u>...)`).

It also works with strings containing unmatched `{` and `}`:

```
>>> # Even works with dangling braces:
>>> badstring = '}oo} { ab  a   b}}  xy {xy  x y}cd {{   cd  } e{e }f{ f}  { }{} }{'
>>> # Fully flattened result:
>>> [s for m in regex.finditer(pattern, badstring, regex.VERBOSE) for s in m.captures('u')]
[' ', '  ', '   ', '  ', ' ', '   ', '  ', ' ', ' ', ' ']
>>> # Less flattened (e.g. for verification):
>>> [v for m in regex.finditer(pattern, badstring, regex.VERBOSE) for v in m.capturesdict().values()]
[[' ', '  ', '   '], ['  ', ' '], ['   ', '  '], [' '], [' '], [' '], []]
```

*Tested on Python 3.5.1 x64, regex 2016.3.2.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws an error: `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`

Comment: I improved my answer so as to actually work. Neither elegant nor readable, it's now correct at least :-)